# Accessing variable in parent scope

Tags: node.js

I have a custom logging function which is assigned to express requests `req.log` object using middleware.

The purpose of this is for the logging funtion to be able to read the request headers.traceid, before transmitting the log event to a seperate service.

This is working perfectly fine using middlware or with an extra parameter in the function, however to simplify the use of it.

What I'd really like to know if there's a way for the function to be able to read the `req` object from the scope it was called in, without referencing it either using middlware or as a function paramter?

```
// log.js

module.exports = () => {
 console.log(...arguments)

 const req = getVarFromParentScope("req") || undefined
 const traceId = req?.headers.traceid || null

 // POST { timestamp, traceId, args: { ...arguments } } to logging service
}
```

Comment: Why not using `module.exports = function () {...}` to not bind the scope?

Comment: @DadiBit — That would only allow a custom value for `this` to be passed in. It gives you nothing more than an argument would, but with more complex syntax.

Comment: Yes of course it's not very useful to do so, but i wanted to point out  that `function () {...}` can be bound to the parent one later on, while `() => {...}` automatically binds to itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it isn't.

(And if it was, then the ability for a function to access a variable inside another function just because it was the calling function would make it very easy to write code that was very hard to debug.)